# opendkim public key not available

Tags: postfix, dkim, milter, opendkim

I'm having problems with my mail server sending or reciving mails from/to hotmail can anyone explain for newbies what all this errors on postfix log/gmail header/website dkim validator are telling me and give me a clue what should i do next?

Centos 7 and Postfix 2.10

I have activated on opendkim.conf:

```
 KeyTable                 refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
 SigningTable                 refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
 ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
 InternalHosts      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
```

my KeyTable file look like:

```
 default._domainkey.example.com example.com:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/example.com/default.private
```

and my TrustedHosts has

```
 127.0.0.1
 example.com
 mail.example.com
```

and of course file default.private exist
I have in main.cf postfix conf file:

```
 smtpd_milters           = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
 non_smtpd_milters       = $smtpd_milters
 milter_default_action   = accept
```

On Opendkim status (systemctl status opendkim.service) shows this on bold text:

```
  opendkim.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT 
  Unit opendkim.service entered failed state.
```

if I use http://dkimvalidator.com/ it gives me in the Validating Signature of DKIM Information:

```
  result = invalid
  Details: public key: not available
```

update dkim txt dns record looks like:

```
 default._domainkey IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; "
   "p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDqqN1PV0SVRxJDroI8sepENY+Z6iH0T4m1cSqnjHOnIQ9beeElpe1zzctpjc9GItgvzi5/jbltb9vBl91BGKhNzaW9qhlbX+dKYWftwdLEFyuNCtEJ12AbYN+dHa48bsPLxSOxXMS2UB0YwcgtOJoERRPl2dvHB5ekR4aZ22qN9QIDAQAB" )
```

When I send to gmail the header Authentication-Results: part gives me something like , anyway gmail is accepting mails:

```
 dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@
```

My log file after send to hotmail:

```
  Mar 13 14:26:55 example.com postfix/smtp: host 30047900.in1.mandrillapp.com[54.71.88.34] said: 454 4.7.1 <2BLZDRqbq1HvOS@dkimvalidator.com@dkimvalidator.com>: Relay access denied (in reply to RCPT TO command)
  Mar 13 14:26:56 example.com postfix/smtp: to=<2BLZDRqbq1HvOS@dkimvalidator.com@dkimvalidator.com>, relay=30047900.in1.mandrillapp.com[54.70.134.182]:25, delay=8580, delays=8578/0.02/1.7/0.24, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host 30047900.in1.mandrillapp.com[54.70.134.182] said: 454 4.7.1 <2BLZDRqbq1HvOS@dkimvalidator.com@dkimvalidator.com>: Relay access denied (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Comment: What is in the DNS TXT record?

Comment: Okay, so that's your SPF record. What is your DKIM DNS TXT record?

Comment: I follow this tutorial https://der-linux-admin.de/2014/08/centos-7-postfix-opendkim-domainkeys-identified-mail/ so my txt record looks like described above.

Comment: What's the output of `dig  default._domainkey.example.com TXT`?

Comment: You can add `+short` on the end of that for a terse output.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: I have set this records with my server provider's control panel but now seems I need my own dns server, so I would set this configuration and if I still have the problem , I would came back here. Thanks

Comment: If this case was resolved, then please put the solution in the answer section, so this question doesn't float in unanswered page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately  due to my server provider's control panel seems I need my own dns server so im going to leave this without and answer at the momment , so I would set this configuration in my new one if I still have the problem , I would came back here. Thanks

Update: I'm going to say in addition that if you follow this tutorial http://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2010/09/how-to-get-dkim-domainkeys-identified-mail-working-on-centos-5-5-and-postfix-using-opendkim/ carefully you might have good results, and

```
result = invalid
Details: public key: not available
```

In my case, I could say that was because my dns record has the wrong syntax , so be sure the name value is like default._sample.com.sample.com (two times in my case) I suposse this depends on where you insert your record: If your are editing you zone file must default._sample.com IN TXT v=DKIM1... (etc , get rid of double quotes) and if you are editing using a web interface control panel , you must ask your privider first.

Hope this help anyone.

Comment: should be this [on hold] @masegaloeh?